# MVC - Limit access to page over time period

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a web application using MVC ASP.net in visual studio for users to make posts on a forum. I would like to **limit user posts to 1 per 24 hours**, denying them access to the form html page in this time period.
The users can post without logging in, so would the best way to save the *ip address?*

---

Would appreciate any examples and where to place the limit.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want this on intranet or Internet? [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you if you are using Internet, for finding ISP IP address.

Comment: Please note, for correct observation, you have to deploy on Public IP